# AS3 - Changing text color inside a sprite, then publish it

Tags: actionscript-3, text, colors, format, containers

I have a sprite-container with some formatted text in it. I know that I can change its color via TextFormat, but a container is quite handy since I put many text fields in it, and I can change their color with a single command.

```
  var textContainer:Sprite =  new Sprite();
  addChild(textContainer);

  var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
  format.size = 12;
  format.font = "Arial";

  var someText:TextField = new TextField();
  someText.defaultTextFormat = format;          
  someText.text = "ABC";            
  textContainer.addChild(someText);

  var colorTransform:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
  colorTransform.color = 0xFF0000; 
  textContainer.transform.colorTransform = colorTransform;
```

Now when I test in the Flash player, the color changes properly.
Instead, when I publish in HTML, for some reason the color doesn't change.

Where I'm wrong?

Comment: Sounds like maybe you're just running into a caching issue in your browser, try to delete the bin-debug folder, refresh to see that things are gone, run a clean build and check again.

Comment: I noticed this happens only with Chrome. IE works fine. Any help?

Comment: Problem solved! :)
Take a look here:
http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/enable-system-flash-player-google-chrome.html

Comment: Ah so the issue was ultimately the internal version of flash player used by chrome has a bug in it at the moment.  It might be worthwhile to search for if the bug has been entered yet on Adobe's end or with Chrome.